# How to modify cache value a drop down list once clicks on input type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache

[image]

I have one text box and the user clicks on it then it's showing a dropdown list for old values.
Is there any workaround to change the date format from dd/mm/yyyy to dd-MMM-yyyy for cache values after the text box click event fired?

Comment: Please show us your code. It's hard to help you without

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen drop down cache value list will visible on any text field e.g
<input type="text" id="createdDate" name="createdDate">